# sorted search increase performance

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

Running through exercises on testdome...currently looking at https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9877

> Implement function `CountNumbers` that accepts a sorted array of integers and counts the number of array elements that are less than the parameter `lessThan`.
>
> For example, `SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4)` should return 2 because there are two array elements less than 4.

I have entered:

```
public class SortedSearch
{
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
         int returnedValued = 0;

            foreach (int i in sortedArray)
            {
                if(i<lessThan)
                returnedValued += 1;
            }

            return returnedValued;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

I was wondering why this was marked as difficulty level hard and expected time 20 min when I knew it should only take a few. Anyway, 2 out of 4 cases passed. I'm failing on time limit exceeded and I'm guessing I need to refactor to return a faster search. Is this right? And if so could anyone help with it?

```
      Example case: Correct answer 
      Various small arrays: Correct answer 
      Performance test when sortedArray contains lessThan: Time limit exceeded 
      Performance test when sortedArray doesn't contain lessThan: Time limit exceeded
```

Comment: I think they expect you to implement some sort of binary search, as the array is already sorted.

Comment: If you want to know why your code failed the test, you need to ask the person who created the test, not the Stack Overflow community. A good question would have some _specific_ actionable information, such as the exact expected behavior and a detailed explanation of what you've tried so far to achieve that behavior and what _specifically_ you are unable to figure out on your own. This question lacks those details, and is likely to elicit a wide variety of different answers. It is too broad and does not contain a clear problem statement.

Comment: Add `Using System.Linq;` then implement your function as `sortedArray.Where(i => i < lessThan).Count();`  Then go take some time to look at Linq and C# closures.

Comment: Also, I just looked at the site, and it does have hints. Did you read any of the hints? If not, why not do that before asking here? If so, what hints did you read, and why did they not help you solve the problem? **Hint: the second hint tells you _exactly_ what you need to do in order to pass the tests.**

Comment: But my previous comment does not help your situation. Your code is failing because you're supposed to take advantage of the fact that the list is already sorted.  Since it is sorted, after reaching some value, you do not need to continue reading `sortedArray`, because you know that either every subsequent value is increasing your count, or every subsequent value is not increasing your count.  Depends on which direction you start from.

Answer (score 8):

This passed all 4 tests:

```
public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    int val = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
    return val < 0 ? ~val : val;
}
```

As others have said, they expect you to use [Array.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which I didn't realise until read the 2nd hint.

Answer (score 4):

They expect you to use the [`Array.BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get 100%.

```
using System;

public class SortedSearch
{
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
        int lengthOfArray = sortedArray.Length;
        if (lengthOfArray == 0) return 0;

        if (sortedArray[0] >= lessThan) return 0;
        if (sortedArray[lengthOfArray - 1] < lessThan) return lengthOfArray;

        int index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
        if (index < 0)
            return ~index;

        return index;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to break the **foreach** loop, once **if** condition get false because we already know given array is sorted so there is no point to keep on evaluating further elements. Please see below code snippet for reference.

```
foreach (int i in sortedArray)
{
    if (i < lessThan)
        returnedValued += 1;
    else break;
}
```

Please see below solution which passed all the 4 tests. I have used binary search technique to find out the element which is greater than **lessThan** variable.

```
public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    //Handle all the corner cases
    int legthOfArray = sortedArray.Length;
    if (legthOfArray == 0) return 0;
    if (sortedArray[0] >= lessThan) return 0;
    if (sortedArray[legthOfArray - 1] < lessThan) return legthOfArray;
    return FindIndexGreaterOrEqualIndex(sortedArray, legthOfArray, lessThan, legthOfArray / 2);
}

public static int FindIndexGreaterOrEqualIndex(int[] sortedArray, int lengthOfArray, int lessThan, int currentIndex)
{
    while (true)
    {
        bool isCurrentElementLessThan = sortedArray[currentIndex] < lessThan;
        if (isCurrentElementLessThan) // Traverse Right hand side of binary tree.
            currentIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(currentIndex + lengthOfArray - 1) / 2);
        else if (sortedArray[currentIndex - 1] < lessThan && !isCurrentElementLessThan) //If array element is not less than and previous element is less than the given element. i.e. our answer so break the loop.
            break;
        else // Traverse Left hand side of binary tree.
            currentIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)currentIndex / 2);
    }
    return currentIndex;
}
```

Have a look :)

Comment: This code runs forever, for the following input:
Console.WriteLine(CountNumbers(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, 5));

Comment: This fails 2 out of 4 tests in the TestDome.com environment.  Although, I appreciate your fixing the OP's example in the first part of your answer.

Comment: For some of my test cases, this runs forever for me, too.  Although, I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to implement your own BST, you can try the following code. It is written in Python. You can rewrite it in other languages if required. It passes all the 4 tests.

```
def count_numbers(sorted_list, less_than):

    if len(sorted_list) == 0 or sorted_list[0] >= less_than:
        return 0
    if sorted_list[-1] < less_than:
        return len(sorted_list)

    arr = sorted_list
    def lt_array(low, high, arr):
        mid = low + (high-low+1) //2 
        if arr[mid] >= less_than and arr[mid-1] < less_than:
            return mid
        if arr[mid] > less_than:
            return lt_array(low,mid,arr)
        else:
            return lt_array(mid, high, arr)
    
    return lt_array(0,len(sorted_list)-1, arr)
```