# Please suggest different approach for this CountNumbers algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays

Implement function `CountNumbers` that accepts a sorted array of unique integers and counts the number of array elements that are less than the parameter `lessThan`

For example, `SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4)` should return 2 because there are two array elements less than 4.

Below is my approach. But the score given by online tool for this is 50%. What am i missing?

```
using System;

public class SortedSearch
{
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
      int iRes=0;
        for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(sortedArray[i]< lessThan)
            {
                iRes=iRes+1;
            }
        }
        return iRes;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Below is my approach. But the score given by online tool for this is 50%. What am i missing?  using System;

public class SortedSearch
{
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
      int iRes=0;
        for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(sortedArray[i]< lessThan)
            {
                iRes=iRes+1;
            }
        }
        return iRes;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805768/how-do-i-increase-the-algorithm-performance-for-longer-array-of-numbers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545024/sortedsearch-countnumbersnew-int-1-3-5-7-4-should-return-2-because-t
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376441/sorted-search-increase-performance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202302/how-to-optimize-a-loops-going-through-arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the algorithm performance for longer array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805768/how-do-i-increase-the-algorithm-performance-for-longer-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Your current solution takes *up to* `O(N)` where `N` is the size of array. You could leverage the fact that your input array is sorted to decrease the time complexity of the solution to [image: eq1] by using [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch__1___0_____0_):

```
public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    var result = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);

    return result >= 0 ? result : -1 * result - 1;
}
```

Why do the strange `-1 * result - 1` code? Because, as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch__1___0_____0_):

> **Returns**
>
> The index of the specified value in the specified array, if value is
>   found; otherwise, a negative number. If value is not found and value
>   is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number
>   returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element
>   that is larger than value. If value is not found and value is greater
>   than all elements in array, the negative number returned is the
>   bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1). If this
>   method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be
>   incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is
>   present in array.

`result - 1` reverses the "bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1)".

[`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch__1___0_____0_) will generally perform faster than `Where` or `TakeWhile` **particularly over large sets of data** - since it will perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

> In computer science, binary search, also known as half-interval
>   search, logarithmic search, or binary chop, is a search algorithm that
>   finds the position of a target value within a sorted array.

The clue to use a binary search is the "accepts a sorted array of unique integers" part of the requirement. My above solution only works, as is, with a sorted array of unique values. It thus seems to me that whomever wrote the online test likely had binary search in mind.

Comment: Didn't realize that the negative number returned is bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. I thought it would have been -1. Thanks for point this out. This is definitely the best answer. Would have been great if you could quote the way negative value is calculated when the element is not found.

Comment: Thats great @mjwills. Score is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Linq for the purpose.

```
int CountNumbers(IEnumerable<int> source,int limit)
{
    return source.TakeWhile(x=>x<limit).Count();
}
```

Since it is already mentioned in OP that the input array is sorted, you can exit your search when you find the first element greater than the limit. [TakeWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8) method would help you in the same.

The above method, would select all elements while the condition  is met, and finds the count of items.

Example.

```
var result = CountNumbers(new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7},4);
Output : 2
```